# Am I allowed to bring my own seat belt extender on a plane?

Tags: airlines, hand-luggage

Just like the title asks:

Am I allowed to bring my own seat belt extender on a plane?

To target a more specific airline, will Singapore airlines allow this?

Comment: Have you called and asked them ?

Comment: Unlikely, since all safety related stuff is tightly regulated and needs to be certified before it can be used on a plane.

Comment: @blackbird57 No, I have not. I had thought of this this morning while at work, and I can't really call from here. I will give them a ring when I get home.

Comment: @Hilmar thanks, I will give them a ring like blackbird57 suggested.

Comment: Since airlines will give you a seatbelt extender if you need one, why would you want to bring your own?

Comment: @DJClayworth Typically I wouldn't care, but I've had two issues where they ran out, LOL.

Comment: If they've run out and you can't fasten your seatbelt without one I'm pretty sure they'll let you use your own rather than not using one at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I got an answer back from Singapore Airlines. They responded from twitter:

> Hi Jason, it is advised that you use the ones on board due to safety
>   concerns, thank you very much.